How to maximally entangle two qubits?
I'm looking for a transformation that entangles two qubits $\mid{\psi}_1\rangle = \alpha_1 {\mid}0\rangle + \beta_1  {\mid}1\rangle$ and $\mid{\psi}_2\rangle = \alpha_2 {\mid}0\rangle + \beta_2  {\mid}1\rangle$. For example, is there a unitary $\hat{U}$ that can map $\mid{\psi}_1\rangle\otimes\mid{\psi}_2\rangle$ to something that looks like, say, $\gamma {\mid}0\rangle\otimes{\mid}0\rangle+\kappa{\mid}1\rangle\otimes{\mid}1\rangle$ or $\gamma {\mid}0\rangle\otimes{\mid}1\rangle+\kappa{\mid}1\rangle\otimes{\mid}0\rangle$ where $\gamma$ and $\kappa$ are functions of $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$, $\beta_1$, and $\beta_2$? If so, how can I construct $\hat{U}$?

Sure: For every two unit vectors there exists a unitary operator which maps one onto the other.

@TobiasFünke Could you please elaborate on that with a full answer? I'm not sure I understand what you mean. What is $\hat{U}$ here?

Well, this is a simple consequence of the Hilbert space structure. See e.g. this Math SE thread.

That question addresses rotations on the Bloch sphere to go from one qubit to the other. It makes no reference to entanglement.

It really does not matter. The answers still apply. See also the linked question(s). While browsing through all of these, I saw several very similar if not the same questions. The answer is always the same, namely my very first comment. And to explicitly construct such a  is explained in the accepted answer in the linked thread and in the linked Math SE thread.

Lastly, see also this Math SE post, which might be useful.
